# Corda Transaction Timestamp

Tags: transactions, timestamp, corda

Could one of you help us on what is the most efficient way to get transaction committed timestamp (execution time or saves time) from a Trandaction Id (SignedTransaction) from RPC; if it is possible?

We maybe should create a flow to get the list of all transactions… Possible?

Here our need: we want to get all transactions with a set of information (Transaction Id, Linear Id (when exists), date and time of the transaction, participants, signers…)

We currently use rpc.internalVerifiedTransactionsSnapshot(); and then go through the list and get the information we need from each line.

We found a way to get the recordTime from statesMetadata but for Issuance Transaction the statesMetadata is empty… There is another object “consumedTime” but we couldn’t get it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> We found a way to get the recordTime from statesMetadata but for
>   Issuance Transaction the statesMetadata is empty… There is another
>   object “consumedTime” but we couldn’t get it.

The reason for this is the notary only timestamps issuance transactions when a time-window is provided. To have a timestamp added, include a time-window or perhaps think about adding a timestamp as a property on the state.

Also with issuances, nothing is being consumed (only inputs are consumed), so you should be looking at recordedTime in StateMetadata.

Comment: This what we we did, we added a property to the state. Thanks for the answer.